# How can I simplify multiple 'then's for asynchronous axios post method?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, async-await, axios

I used an axios `POST method` to post multiple things through an API using consecutive `then`s.

To fix the hard-coded `then`s, I tried to use a for loop(used let, for..of, Promise.all, and etc.) but it doesn't work as I expected raising

```
File "C:\Python\Python3.6.3\lib\wsgiref\simple_server.py", line 35, in close
self.status.split(' ',1)[0], self.bytes_sent
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
```

error(django backend).

This is the source code(.vue file).

```
//defaultHttpClient is an axios call

const labelList = this.newLabel.text.split(" ");
this.copiedLabels = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.newLabel));

async function putLabel(i, response, newLabel, copiedLabels, labels){
     copiedLabels.text = newLabel.text.split(" ")[i]
     await defaultHttpClient.post(`/v1/projects/${response.data.id}/labels`, copiedLabels)  
      //API call
      }


//tried to make multiple API calls but this was the only way to make it possible.

      defaultHttpClient.post('/v1/projects', payload)
        .then((response) => {
          window.location = `/projects/${response.data.id}/docs/create`;
          return response;
        })
        .then((response)=> {
          putLabel(0, response, this.newLabel, this.copiedLabels, this.labels);
          return response;
        })
        .then((response)=> {
          putLabel(1, response, this.newLabel, this.copiedLabels, this.labels);         
          return response;
        })
        .then((response)=> {
          putLabel(2, response, this.newLabel, this.copiedLabels, this.labels);         
          return response;
        })
```

How could we simplify the hard-coded `then`s or make it work better?

Comment: Try using **async/await** correctly which might reduce the complexity and increases the readability.

Comment: @SivaneshS I could have solved the problem with async/await. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `async` and `await` to simplify:

```
async function someFunction() {

      try {
          let response = await defaultHttpClient.post('/v1/projects', payload)
          await putLabel(0, response, this.newLabel, this.copiedLabels, this.labels);
          await putLabel(1, response, this.newLabel, this.copiedLabels, this.labels);         
          await putLabel(2, response, this.newLabel, this.copiedLabels, this.labels);         
          window.location = `/projects/${response.data.id}/docs/create`;
      } catch(e) {
          // put some error handling code here
      }
 }
```

---

Just so you understand, your original code would not have worked at all.  `window.location` would have changed the current page before all your `putLabel()` calls got a chance to execute.  You need to complete everything you want done BEFORE you set `window.location` to a new page.

In addition, all your `.then()` handlers were not coded to execute in proper sequence because none of them waited for each `putLabel()` to finish.  To do that, you would have to use the promise that they return, but you were just ignoring that.

---

You can further simplify putLabel to this:

```
function putLabel(i, response, newLabel, copiedLabels, labels) {
     copiedLabels.text = newLabel.text.split(" ")[i]
     return defaultHttpClient.post(`/v1/projects/${response.data.id}/labels`, copiedLabels)  
      //API call
}
```

It is important to remember that an `await` pauses the internal execution of a function, but an `async` function still immediately returns a promise as soon as it hits the first `await`.  So, your `await` in `putLabel()` wasn't accomplishing anything and wasn't keeping `putLabel()` from returning before the `.post()` call was done.

---

It also appears that there's no particular reason that your `putLabel()` calls have to be done in sequence where the 2nd waits for the 1st to finish and that maybe they can all be run in parallel.  If that's the case, then you could run them like this:

```
async function someFunction() {

      try {
          let response = await defaultHttpClient.post('/v1/projects', payload)
          await Promise.all([
              putLabel(0, response, this.newLabel, this.copiedLabels, this.labels),
              putLabel(1, response, this.newLabel, this.copiedLabels, this.labels),         
              putLabel(2, response, this.newLabel, this.copiedLabels, this.labels)
          ]);         
          window.location = `/projects/${response.data.id}/docs/create`;
      } catch(e) {
          // put some error handling code here
      }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Your suggestions helped me a lot to solve the problem. I don't know why it only works when the code is executed in sequence but solved it anyhow!

Answer (score 0):

```
const apicall = async () => {

  const res1 = await defaultHttpClient.post('/v1/projects', payload)

  window.location = `/projects/${res1.data.id}/docs/create`;

  const res2 = putLabel(0, res1, this.newLabel, this.copiedLabels, this.labels);

  const res3 = putLabel(1, res2, this.newLabel, this.copiedLabels, this.labels);         
  const res4 =  putLabel(2, res3, this.newLabel, this.copiedLabels, this.labels);         
  return res4;
}
```

Call this function, here we are using async await, to make the code simpler and readable, and it will return a promise.

Comment: using async like this helped me to solve the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting an error in python, you should verify that the payload - what you are sending to the python backend - is correct. The Javascript part itself doesn't have much to do it with it.

However your code be improved a bit, by avoiding to do additional operations after a redirect and try to do the subsequent calls to `putLabel` in parallel, using `Promise.all` instead of sequential, which is what you get if you use multiple `await` calls one after the other

```
defaultHttpClient.post('/v1/projects', payload).then(response => {
  // according to your code, in all calls of `putLabel`
  // you're using the first response which you receive from the
  // `/v1/projects` endpoint 
  Promise.all([
    putLabel(0, response, this.newLabel, this.copiedLabels, this.labels),
    putLabel(1, response, this.newLabel, this.copiedLabels, this.labels),
    putLabel(2, response, this.newLabel, this.copiedLabels, this.labels)
  ]).then(() => {
    // all promises have finished so we can redirect
    window.location = `/projects/${response.data.id}/docs/create`;
  })
})
```

Comment: Great insight! Let me take a look at the payload as you said.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have background with blocking programming languages but `JS` is `non-blocking` which means your code is not executed from top to bottom **unless** it is inside an `async` function with a `await` before any asynchronous function call (best way for dealing with non-blocking with a blocking languages background).

Unfortunately this doesn't work outside of a function so you need to put API calls in a function body. As far as I see you can abstract the counter in a for loop so:

```
async function apiCalls(max = 2) {
  let response = await defaultHttpClient.post('/v1/projects', payload)
  window.location = `/projects/${response.data.id}/docs/create`
  for (let i = 0; i <= max; i++) {
    response = await putLabel(i, response, this.newLabel, this.copiedLabels, this.labels)
  }
}
```

But this way your API calls are run in sequence which means the total function call time is sum of all calls, but if you don't need the response from previous call in the next call then you can use `Promise.all` as suggested by others. That way your function call time is as long as the lengthiest API call (all calls are done simultaneously) so:

```
async function apiCalls(max = 2) {
  let response = await defaultHttpClient.post('/v1/projects', payload)
  window.location = `/projects/${response.data.id}/docs/create`
  const reqs = []
  for (let i = 0; i <= max; i++) {
    reqs.push(putLabel(i, response, this.newLabel, this.copiedLabels, this.labels))
  }
  await Promise.all(reqs)
}
```

Using a `try/catch` you can catch and throw/rethrow errors inside an `async` function (recommended in your case).